# Set value of property in IQueryable<T> after join with another table based on some conditions

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, automapper, iqueryable

I am implementing Authorization for WPF. I have bound permissions with screens. For example, there is a screen called floor. It has four permissions associated with it.

1. View Floor
2. Add Floor
3. Edit Floor
4. Delete Floor

Along with every permission we have four levels of permissions.

1. All
2. Self
3. Role
4. User

So, if users have {View Floor} permission with permission level {ALL}. They can view all floors created by any user.

If users have {Self} Permission Level. They can only view floors created by themselves.

If a user has a Permission Level of {Role}. They can view all floors assigned against specified roles.

*Roles for Permission Level are assigned like this:*

```
Roles: Supervisor, Technician
```

If a BranchManager has the above Permission Level. Then he can view floors created by himself and created by any users who are having the role of supervisor or technician.

Permission Level {User} is same as {Role}.

Here is my IQueryable to fetch floors:

```
IQueryable<FloorModel> FloorsQueryable = (from f in Floors
                                          join b in Branches on f.BranchId equals b.Id
                                          where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filters.Name) || f.Name.ToLower().Contains(filters.Name.ToLower()))
                                          && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filters.BranchName) || b.Name.ToLower().Contains(filters.BranchName.ToLower()))
                                          && (f.IsDeleted == null || f.IsDeleted == false)
                                          && f.BranchId == CurrentBranchId
                                          && f.ApplicationId == CurrentApplicationId
                                          select new FloorModel
                                          {
                                              Id = f.Id,
                                              Name = f.Name,
                                              Code = f.Code,
                                              Branch = new BranchBriefModel()
                                              {
                                                  Id = f.BranchId,
                                                  Name = b.Name,
                                              },
                                              IsActive = f.IsActive ?? false,
                                              Description = f.Description,
                                              CreatedBy = f.CreatedBy ?? 0,
                                              ApplicationId = CurrentApplicationId,
                                          }).AsQueryable();
```

After this I need to apply some custom filter to this query based on Permission Level

```
FloorsQueryable = CustomFilter(FloorsQueryable,CurrentUserId,filters);
```

**CustomFilter Code**

```
public IQueryable<T> CustomFilter<T>(IQueryable<T> query, int CurrentUserId, BaseSearchModel search) where T : BaseModel, new()
{
    var distinctClaims = search.ScreenPermission.Select(x => x.Claim.PermissionLevel).Distinct().ToList();
    var viewPermission = search.ScreenPermission.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("View")).FirstOrDefault();
    if (viewPermission != null && viewPermission.Claim.PermissionLevel != PermissionLevelCatalog.All)
    {
        if (distinctClaims.Any(x => x == PermissionLevelCatalog.Role))
        {
            query = (from q in query
                     join ur in UsersInRoles on q.CreatedBy equals ur.UserId
                     join r in Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
                     select q);
        }
        string propertyName = "CreatedBy";
        //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
        //    return query;
        // we have parameter "generic"
        var selectorParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "generic");
        // constant "CurrentUserId"
        var searchTermExpression = Expression.Constant(CurrentUserId);
        // "generic.CreatedBy"
        var selector = Expression.PropertyOrField(selectorParameter, propertyName);
        // "generic.CreatedBy == "CurrentUserId"
        var equal = Expression.Equal(selector, searchTermExpression);
        // generic => generic.Name == "CurrentUserId"
        var genericWhere = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equal, selectorParameter);
        query = query.Where(genericWhere);
    }
    return query;
}
```

Now for Permission Level {Role} I need to add CreatorRoleId in select clause of IQueryable to apply the required check in the following code.

```
if (distinctClaims.Any(x => x == PermissionLevelCatalog.Role))
{
    query = (from q in query
            join ur in UsersInRoles on q.CreatedBy equals ur.UserId
            join r in Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
            select q
            );
}
```

Is it possible to some how set the value of CreatorRoleId? Some thing like the following

```
select {q=>q.CreatorRoleId=r.Id return q;}
```

This is supposed to be generic and run for any IQueryable. I do not want to join Role and UserInRole table for all the queries in project because these joins are only needed when some user has this {Role} Permission Level.

Comment: you did all the hard work, for this think simple!
Select(x=> new { CreatorRoleId=r.Id } );  let me know if this is what you needed

Comment: @AsımGündüz I have already selected few items in Iqueryable. I need to set this property in already selected items. This will override previous selected properties.

Comment: Just add the other selected fields too or type your original select statement as below,  Seperate them with comas and you can also give them alias 

Select(x=> new { CreatorRoleId=r.Id , field1,field2,ALIASNAME=r.Id});

Comment: @AsımGündüz I Don't know the fields name that were selected its Iqueryable<T> and I don't want to iterate over all properties and select them. Because models can be long and I don't set all the properties in select clause

Comment: Sounds like XY problem. Why `Select`? Isn't the whole idea to add dynamically `Where` filter based on roles? A bit more complicated than the shown `x.CreatedBy == CurrentUserId`, but still `Where`, not `Select`.

Comment: @IvanStoev Can you please show me an example?. It gives me exception if I add a where clause because its not it the select clause.